# Por qué cuando hago una instancia en java y le pongo paquetes me dice que no puede encontrar el símbolo

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo java y estoy con el tema de modificadores de acceso cuando intento llamar estos atributos de otra clase pero en el mismo paquete me dice que no encuentra el símbolo.

```
package paquete_a;

public class Modificadores{

    public static String publico; 
    private static String privado; 
    protected static String Protegido; 
    String PorDefecto;

}
```

Esta es la clase que uso para poder acceder al atributo publico declarado en la otra clase.

```
package paquete_a; 

public class EnElMismoPaquete{ 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Modificadores modificadores = new Modificadores(); 
        modificadores.publico = "Acediendo desde el mismo paquete"; 
        System.out.println(modificadores.publico); 

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema surge porque estas declarando las variables como `static` y las variables estáticas solo pueden ser accedidas por la clase, no por el objeto. `Modificadores` es la clase y `modificadores` es el objeto. Para acceder a variables `static` tiene que ser de la siguiente manera:

```
Modificadores.publico;
```

Si quieres acceder a las variables desde un objeto de la clase `Modificares` tienes que quitarle el `static` a las variables.

```
package paquete_a;

public class Modificadores{

    public String publico; 
    private String privado; 
    protected String Protegido; 
    String PorDefecto;

}
```

De esta manera podras llamarlas desde el objeto.

```
package paquete_a; 

public class EnElMismoPaquete{ 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Modificadores modificadores = new Modificadores(); 
        modificadores.publico = "Acediendo desde el mismo paquete"; 
        System.out.println(modificadores.publico); 

    } 
}
```

Para acceder a variables privadas tienes que declarar los métodos `get` y `set`, que no son mas que método públicos a través de los cuales se puede acceder al valor de las variables.

```
package paquete_a;

public class Modificadores{

    public String publico; 
    private String privado; 
    protected String Protegido; 
    String PorDefecto;

    public void setPrivado(String privado) {
        this.privado = privado;
    }

    public String getPrivado() {
        return privado;
    }

}
```

De esta manera podrás acceder a la variable `privado` de la clase `Modificadores`.

```
package paquete_a; 

public class EnElMismoPaquete{ 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Modificadores modificadores = new Modificadores(); 
        modificadores.setPrivado("Acediendo desde el mismo paquete"); 
        System.out.println(modificadores.getPrivado); 

    } 
}
```

Comment: Gracias men, voy a probrar ahora

Comment: David todavia me sigue asiendo lo mismo

Comment: Con cual variable.

Comment: puede subir una captura del error y compartir el enlace.

Comment: Si claro, ya  lo hago

Comment: David hay esta la imagen, para ver si puede ayudarme

Comment: El problema es `setPrivado()` porque ne la clase `Modificadores` no tienes ningun metodo declarado con ese nombre. Prueba con `modificadores.publico = "Accediendo desde otro paquete";` y luego imprimelo y veras que no te dará error.

Comment: Sigue dandome el mismo problema, Mira

Comment: He editado mi pregunta, agregue una explicación de como acceder a variables privadas. Otra cosa, si mi respuesta han sido de ayuda recuerde dar las gracias de manera constructiva, como dando un **voto** a favor o marcando la respuesta como **aceptada**, tal como se explica en el **[recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** del sitio.

Comment: Ok david pero ayudame pliss

Comment: A ambas clases quitele la sentencia `package paquete_a;` pruebe y me deja saber

Comment: Lo hice y se ejecuta correctamente, pero necesito hacerlo con los paquetes, ese el el ejercicio....

Comment: El nombre de los paquetes debe ser el nombre de la carpeta, en tu caso `package Eagle1;`.

Comment: Tu crees, lo hice con otro archivo ejecurtando desde la misma clase utitlizando paquetes y se ejecuta correctamente sin fallos

Comment: Bien, entonces vuelve a añadirles los `packages paquete_a;` y en la clase `EnElMismoPaquete` agrega el import de la clase Modificadores `import paquete_a.Modificadores;`

Comment: Tambien lo hice y me da el mismo error, no se que loquera tiene esto

Comment: La verdad no tengo ni idea porque el error entonces, desarrollar **java** desde **Sublime Text** no es la mejor opción. Te recomiendo que utilices un **IDE** como **Eclipce** o **NeatBeans**, eso te facilitara la vida y te ahorrara muchos dolores de cabezas, como el de ahora.

Comment: Tendre que hacerlo

Comment: Dos ultimas cosa, borre la respuesta que contiene las imágenes(o mejor, agreguelas a la pregunta) y recuerde dar gracias de manera constructiva.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mira este error, me puedes decir de que sera ....

Answer (score 0):

Podrias subir el codigo de todos los .java que usas?
O por lo menos sacar la foto del codigo?

Creo que en la clase 'EnElMismoPaquete' te falta una llave '}' que cierra.

Answer (score 0):

En las imágenes que pasaste no veo si tienes las llaves de cierre, pareciera que te falta cerrar la función main o la clase.

Acabo de correr tu código y todo me resulto bien, deberías cambiar de IDE, si estas aprendiendo Java entonces empieza a aprender también a utilizar Eclipse.

Acá te dejo mi código:

**EnElMismoPaquete.java**

```
package paquete_a;

public class EnElMismoPaquete{ 

   public static void main(String[] args) { 

       Modificadores modificadores = new Modificadores(); 
       modificadores.publico = "Acediendo desde el mismo paquete"; 
       System.out.println(modificadores.publico); 

   } 
}
```

**Modificadores.java**

```
package paquete_a;

public class Modificadores{

    public String publico; 
    private String privado; 
    protected String Protegido; 
    String PorDefecto;

    public void setPrivado(String privado) {
        this.privado = privado;
    }

    public String getPrivado() {
        return privado;
    }

}
```